# nested resources in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My routes file is:

```
resources :countries do
  resources :regions do 
    resources :appartments
  end
end
```

models:

```
Country: has_many :regions

Region: belongs_to :country, has_many :appartments

Appartment: belongs_to: region
```

Region_controller:

```
def index
  @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
  @regions = @country.regions
end


def show
  @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
  @region = @country.regions.find(params[:id])
end
```

Question:

I want to show appartments on the region page. What's the best practice in my region controller?

Comment: Feel free to ignore my edit, @apneadiving got to it before I did. Do you want to show apartments that belong to the region being viewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would simply be:

```
@appartments = @region.appartments
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to show apartments within the regions show page, do the following:

1. create an instance variable in the regions show action as:

   `@appartments = @regions.appartments`
2. create a partial `_appartments.html.erb` in the `views/regions` folder
3. Somewhere within the `regions/show.html.erb` page, place this:

   `<%= render @appartments %>`

This should do the trick.

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for the edit, I went with my intuition and wrote **apartments**.

Comment: I think you created the partial with name **appartment**, it should be **appartments**. I hope it works.

Comment: partial created: <% @country.region.appartments.each do |appartment| %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to appartment.item.name %></td>

  </p>
<% end %>  but i got the message "undefined method `region' for #<Country:0x200272c>"  What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your **Country** model **has_many** countries, not one country. Hence, you need to iterate through the array of regions. This is what you need to do: **<%= @country.regions.each do |region| %> <%= region.appartments.each do |apt| %> <%= link_to apt.item.name %> <% end %> <% end %>**. Did that **appartments** partial not work? It should work. Did you change the partial name from **_apartment.html.erb** to **_apartments.html.erb** ?

Comment: It is working now.thanks!.....appartments.each do |appartment|
  
  <%= link_to appartment.item_name, country_region_appartment_url(@country, @region, appartment)...but the  record is printed 2 times! is my each loop not correct?

Comment: It should print only once. Maybe your partial is working too. Is that the case?

Comment: You can paste your code snippet from regions/show.html.erb page, would be easier for me to tell.